# Override protocol generic method

Tags: ios, swift

I have one protocol APIResponseHandler. Which has function handleResponse. Which takes responseData and error and returns T. Type of T will depend on it's implementation it will return Dictionary when response is JSON or return NSData in some case. Any Idea how can i do that

```
protocol APIResponseHandler {
    func handleResponse<T>(responseData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> (T?, NSError?)
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want an `associatedtype`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give Swift a hint of what `T` is:

```
protocol APIResponseHandler {
    func handleResponse<T>(responseData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> (T?, NSError?)
}

class MyClass: APIResponseHandler {
    func handleResponse<T>(responseData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> (T?, NSError?) {
        print(T)
        return (nil, nil)
    }
}

let obj = MyClass()

// Telling Swift T is a [String: String] dictionary
let result: ([String: String]?, NSError?) = obj.handleResponse(nil, error: nil)
```